# Spectral theorem for compact operators on Banach space.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space. Let $A$ be a compact operator on $X$ and let's denote $\sigma(A)$ is spectrum of operator $A$. Let $f$ be holomorphic function in some neighbourhood of $\sigma(A)$

Out theacher sais that then there is exists a map $f \to f(A) \in B(X)$ (compact operators on $X$), such as :

1)$\alpha f_1(A) + \beta f_2(A) = (\alpha f_1 + \beta f_2)(A)$

2)$f_1 (f_2(A)) = f_1(A)\cdot f_2(A)$

3)$f(z) = \sum a_n z^n$ , then $f(A) = \sum a_n A^n$.

It looks good, but in Hilbert space, not in Banach. Is it true in general? Maybe I can read about it somewhere?

Comment: See Rudin "Functional Analysis". Btw (2) is stated wrong; if say $f_1(z)=z$ then $f_1(f_2(A))=f_2(A)$ while $f_(A)f_2(A)=Af_2(A)$.

Comment: I bet (2) was supposed to be $(f_1f_2)(A)=f_1(A)f_2(A)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For introductory notes read Wikipedia:

[Holomorphic Functional Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_functional_calculus)

For follow-up, I would suggest, [Perturbation Theory](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/kato1.pdf), by Tosio Kato.

Comment: Thanks a lot! There is a chapter in wiki with following problem!